# TF2.0 Data API get n_i samples from each class label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I have to classify inputs of shape 32x32 into 3 classes using a TF2 Keras model. My training set has 7000 examples

```
>>> X_train.shape # (7000, 32, 32)
>>> Y_train.shape # (7000, 3)
```

The number of examples for each class varies (e.g. class_0 has ~2500 examples while class_1 has ~800, etc.)

I want to use the tf.data API to create a dataset object that returns batches of training data with no. of examples from each class specified by `[n_0, n_1, n_2]`.

I would like to have these `n_i` samples from each class randomly drawn with replacement from `X_train, Y_train`

For example, if I call `get_batch([100, 150, 125])` it should return 100 random samples from `X_batch` from class_0, 150 from class_1, and 125 from class_2.

How can I achieve this using the TF2.0 Data API so I could use it for training a Keras model?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to proceed as follows:

1. Load the data from `X_train` & `Y_train` into a single `tf.data` Dataset so that we ensure we keep each `X` matched with the correct `Y`
2. `.shuffle()` then split the dataset into each `n_i` using a `filter()`
3. Write our `get_batch` function to return the correct number of samples from each dataset, `shuffle()` the sample then split it back into `X` & `Y`

Something like this:

```py
# 1: Load the data into a Dataset
raw_data = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
    (
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Y_train)
    )
  ).shuffle(7000)


# 2: Split for each category
def get_filter_fn(n):
  def filter_fn(x, y):
    return tf.equal(1.0, y[n])
  return filter_fn

n_0s = raw_data.filter(get_filter_fn(0))
n_1s = raw_data.filter(get_filter_fn(1))
n_2s = raw_data.filter(get_filter_fn(2))

# 3:
def get_batch(n_0,n_1,n_2):
  sample = n_0s.take(n_0).concatenate(n_1s.take(n_1)).concatenate(n_2s.take(n_2))
  shuffled = sample.shuffle(n_0 + n_1 + n_2)
  return shuffled.map(lambda x,y: x),shuffled.map(lambda x,y: y)
```

So now we can do:

```py
x_batch, y_batch = get_batch(100, 150, 125)
```

Note that I've used some potentially wasteful operations here pursuing an approach I find intuitive and straightforward (specifically reading the `raw_data` dataset 3 times for the filter operations) so I make no claim that this is the most efficient way to accomplish what you need but for a dataset that fits in memory like the one you describe I'm sure such inefficiencies will be negligible

Answer (score 1):

Keras' [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) actually has a parameter for that. While it doesn't let you pick exact number of samples, it selects them evenly from the classes.

```
X_train_stratified, X_test_stratified, y_train_strat, y_test_strat = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)
```

If you want to do cross validation you can also use [stratified shuffle split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

I hope I understood your question correctly